# How long does it take $500$ people to introduce themselves to each other?

Tags: combinatorics

> There are $500$ people in a room who all want to introduce themselves to each other. It takes $2.30$ minutes per introduction.
>
> How many meet-ups will there be? How long will the task take?

Comment: Id like to know the total meet ups and not how many times an indivudal will meet anothe person.

Comment: How many pairs of people are in the room? $\binom{500}{2}$.

Comment: Are the introductions in parallel?  Do they split up into $250$ pairs and introduce themselves to each other?  Does that take $2.30$ or $4.60$ minutes?  Or does one person stand at the front and introduce himself/herself to everybody?

Comment: By 2.30 minutes, do you mean 2 minutes, 30 seconds; or do you mean 2 minutes, 18 seconds?

Comment: @rossMillikan Yes they will be, all simultaneously.

Comment: @paw88789 No as in actual time, thats what makes it slightly harder, as 60 seconds in a minute.

Answer (score 1):

Let's figure out how many meet-ups occur. Each person in the room will introduce themselves to $n-1$ other people (since they don't meet-up with themselves). So there will be $n(n-1)$ introductions. However, we have counted each introduction twice so we divide by two so our final answer is $$\frac{n(n-1)}{2}=\frac{500(499)}{2}=124,750$$

Now, let's think about total time for this event to occur. We have $500$ total people so there will be $\frac{500}{2}=250$ total meetings occuring simultaneously. Thus we divide the total number of meetings by $250$ to see how many "sessions" are needed for everyone to have met. Then
$\frac{124,750}{250}=499$ total "sessions" occur for each individual to have met one another. Multiply this by $2.5$ to get $$499\cdot2.5=1,247.5$$ minutes total.

Comment: Yes, but can we manage the task so that we can always have 250 simultaneous meetings? A naïve approach works only if the number of people is a power of $2$: Divide the group in two equal groups, arrange them in two concentric circles, and let the people in the outer circle move clockwise, one step at a time. When done, divide each group in two again, and repeat the procedure in parallel with each of the smaller groups, and so on. But I can't immediately see a way to do it with 500 people.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen if 250 people stand across each other? then move along.

Comment: @KashifHussain Yes, that is the first part of the solution I outlined. But after 250 steps, all the people in the first half are introduced to all the people in the second half. However, none of the people in each half have been introduced to each other. Here's the rub: After the vast majority of introductions are done, you may no longer be able to find 250 disjoint pairs of people who are still unintroduced (if that is a word).

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen That was the same problem I was struggling 10 minutes earlier. Follow paw88789s link and you will see a way how to do this (rotate everyone but keep the host fixed).

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen you are putting stipulations on the problem that are not there. Nowhere in the problem does it even say these introductions need to be physical, just that the people are in the same room. They could all be on Skype or a video chat service that automatically transitions them to the next introduction at the 2.5 minute mark.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen And further, if physical stipulations were put into the problem, everyone could stand in a circle and half of the group could rotate after each session. (of course if we were being entirely literal here there would still be fractions of a second added in the time it took for a person to step around the person they just met with to get to the next)

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Circular motion? What if the 250 start by facing each other then move along in a circular motion. If A meets D, B meets E and C Meets F, then after 2.30mins Everyone moves to the clockwise. So A will meet F, B will meet C and D will meet E.

Comment: I never said anything about physical stipulations, other than the presumed impossibility of one person to be introduced to more than one other person at a time. And I totally do not get this about circular motion. What you suggest seems just like the first step in my proposed solution: 250 people in a circle, the other 250 get introduced to those in the circle, then move to the next one, and so one. At the end, $250\times250$ introductions are complete. But we need $250\times249$ *more* introductions, so we are just over half done yet.

Comment: @ctst Ah, not being much interested in sports, I wasn't aware of the round robin tournament solution. That does indeed solve it in the minimal number of steps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

They present themselves in the same time.

Then by symmetry , just evaluate the time for $1$ to meet the $499$ other people, then it is

$499 x 2.5'$ minutes = $24$ h $47$' $30$ ''

then it is not possible if they are human

Comment: my answer is correct = 250*499.

Comment: @ctst : you are right but the question is about 500 and not 501 ! ok ?

Comment: downvote this answer ? just comment to get me laugh

Comment: @ctst Getting all the handshakes going simultaneously works fine.  It is essentially scheduling a round-robin tournament.  With an even number of participants, everyone is active in every round.  Here's a link.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament

Comment: @igael  I don't see how your multiplication comes out to 47 plus hours.  It should be much closer to 20 hours.

Comment: @ctst : set a table with sequential meetings and go row by row. You can complete upper rows with downer rows until the half of the table

Comment: @paw88789 : thank you, sorry :)

Answer (score -1):

there will be

499+498+....+1=250*499 introductions.